# How we write and run "hello world" program in Types Script in Note Pad

Tags: typescript

i want write and run  a simple "hello world" program in typescript in Note Pad with out using the Visual Studio code ,

Comment: Install node, install tsc, write your program `console.log('Hello world');` in a `hello-world.ts` file. Run `tsc hello-world.ts`, that will transpile your `.ts` to `.js`. Now with JS you can either attach it to `index.html` or run it with node.js.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, why in the name of god you would like to do that?

TypeScript is not a real language, its just a wrapper for native javascript which is the only language nodejs can use.. there is a "tsc" which is the TypeScript Compiler.. it has no connection to the IDE you are working with. you could write the code in NotePad and then you'll have to run the compiler which result in javascript files output that you can run with simple 
`node xxx.js` command..

The IDE just makes it easier and shorter and dose the copmiling task for you and keeps clean and convenient environment..

Hope this info helps in certain way

Comment: And what makes you think it's not a "real" language :) If Microsoft defines it as programing language, why can't you :)

Comment: haha i'm just being strict... my main everyday programming language is TS and one of my favourites. but as a Junior it can be confusing.. you are breaking into an open door ;) i think you cannot use typescript without understanding what stands behind it and how it related to javascript.

Comment: Well, with your logic we should also understand machine code, as in the end typescript is executed as low level instructions. And, you can execute a .ts file or ts statement with ts-node.

Comment: C'mon i didn't say running .ts files is impossible. i have seen a "junior" question and found it reasonable to give a basic answer that will help to proceed. i'm sad you didn't liked it.